# XCode 5 Instruments - missing Stacktrace

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Using Version 5.0.1 (51168) the stacktrace has disappeared, regardless of what kind of application I am running in debug mode on my device.

[image]

The *.dsym seems to be created correctly, I did also try to resymbolicate, without success.

Any idea what options there are left?

Comment: Did you make sure you're using a development provisioning profile? In the past I've found Xcode willing to install an ad hoc distribution build but not to debug it in any capacity. This is a comment rather than an answer since I can't say confidently that Xcode still exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: There is a stack backtrace on the right. Perhaps you just need to move the slider at the bottom to see the intermediate frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the slider to the right for more detail:

[image]

Comment: np, I have been caught by similar sliders many times. It seems like Apple can many times pick the worst defaults.

Comment: Normally I am developing with Xamarin tools, so I am not that familar with the Apple tools yet. Actually I have never been faced with that kind of sliders, but as I did invest hours before asking here, I will look even closer in the future ;-)

Comment: The Xcode "Debug Navigator" has a similar slider, that is where I usually screw-up, I generally fail to look.